# What is being "loaded in" in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, transitivity, parsing

Here is a [quote](https://goo.gl/EioRyr) from "Chapter 3:  Processes" of the third edition of "*[Understanding the Linux Kernel:  From I/O Ports to Process Management](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596005652)*" by Bovet and Cesati:

> The steps performed by the [`__switch_to_`] function are the following:
>   …
>   4. **Loads in the Global Descriptor Table of the local CPU the Thread-Local
>   Storage (TLS) segments used by the `next_p` process**; the three Segment Selectors are stored in the `tls_array` inside the process descriptor (see the section "Segmentation in Linux" in Chapter 2).
>   `cpu_gdt_table[cpu][6] = next_p->thread.tls_array[0]`
>   `cpu_gdt_table[cpu][7] = next_p->thread.tls_array[1]`
>   `cpu_gdt_table[cpu][8] = next_p->thread.tls_array[2]`
>   …

In the bolded text, is the "Global Descriptor Table" being loaded into the "TLS segments" or are the "TLS segments" being loaded into the "Global Descriptor Table"?

Comment: This question might not be on-topic for ELL, because understanding how these terms are related to each other is a programming topic.

Comment: @Jasper Understanding the Linux kernel 3rd edition 
Chapter 3 :Process Switch

Comment: If you have reason to be reading that sentence you should already know enough about what GDTs and TLS segments are, so it should be obvious which gets loaded into the other. But the construction *Load in A B* is always likely to be clumsy phrasing anyway - the idiomatic form is *Load B **into** A* (note the change of preposition). For a more familiar example, compare *Please put sugar in my coffee* (normal English) and *Please put in my coffee sugar* (which is just non-idiomatic [Yoda-speak)](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/yoda-grammar)

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- Your comment would be a good answer.

Comment: @Jasper: I already voted to close the question. It's a terrible example from *our* point of view, since most native speakers wouldn't have any idea what GDT and TLS segments are anyway. But if the OP *had* asked whether *Please put in my coffee sugar* was "valid" (or even worse, if he'd asked what was supposed to be put in what), surely everyone else would have closevoted by now.

Comment: If the direct object is placed after the indirect, we would use "into" here, not "in". *He put into a box marked "Private" the letter he had received from his lawyer.*  *It loads into the local CPU's Global Descriptor Table the Thread-Local Storage (TLS) segments used by the next_p process.* The post-positioning is valid syntax, and is often used when the direct-object-phrase is an especially long one. It keeps the verb-phrase contiguous.

Comment: I wonder if this question could be saved by abstracting away the technical terms and looking at it as a question about how the clauses related and not what this particular sentence means. `The steps performed are the following : 4. Loads in the fizz of the buzz the blip used by the furp;` It seems pretty complicated - I almost think it should be Loads into the GDT. @FumbleFingers heh I substituted GDP for GDT - guess who has been working in financial services too long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it [here](https://goo.gl/EioRyr).

Looking at the code, you should understand by yourself. It means, the TLS segments are being loaded into the Global Descriptor Table.

Comment: yeah you're right.thanks. should've checked the code before asking

Answer (score 0):

This clause has the following structure:

**The `__switch_to_` function** -- This is an implied (or shared) subject, at the start of a list.

**4.** -- The following text is the fourth step in a list of steps.

**Loads** -- verb

**in** -- preposition. This sentence would be clearer if "in" were changed to "into".

**the Global Descriptor Table of the local CPU** -- object of the prepositional phrase, which describes the destination of the loading action.  This is an indirect object of the verb "loads".

**the Thread-Local Storage (TLS) segments** -- direct object of the verb "loads".  This is the loading action's source data.

**used by the next_p process** -- modifier.  It happens to modify the direct object, but it would also be grammatically correct to assume that it describes how the data will be used after being loaded into the Global Descriptor Table.  The code sample clarifies that the first possibility is correct, and that the second possibility is incorrect.

**;** -- semi-colon marks the end of the clause.